# PostGIS layer works in Mapserver 6.4 but fails in 7

Tags: postgis, mapserver

I have the following layer defined in a mapfile:

```
            LAYER

                NAME "aggregates"
                #STATUS OFF
                TYPE POLYGON
                CONNECTIONTYPE POSTGIS
                CONNECTION "host=localhost port=5432 dbname=*** user=*** password=***"
                DATA "geom FROM (SELECT b.geom AS geom, a.peril_id, a.portfolio_id, a.tiv, a.thematic_tiv, a.aggregates_id FROM schema.aggregates a INNER JOIN gisdata.adm_1 b on a.gid = b.gid) AS c using SRID=4326 using unique aggregates_id"

                PROJECTION
                    "proj=longlat"
                    "ellps=WGS84"
                    "datum=WGS84"
                    "no_defs"
                END

            END
```

This works in Mapserver 6.4. However, when I try to use this with Mapserver 7, I get the following errors logged when I try to generate tiles:

```
            [Wed Jun  7 03:42:43 2017].502983 msDrawMap(): rendering using outputformat named png (AGG/PNG).
            [Wed Jun  7 03:42:43 2017].503018 msDrawMap(): WMS/WFS set-up and query, 0.000s
            [Wed Jun  7 03:42:43 2017].523359 msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Error (ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
            LINE 1: ...2300166285,129.462890606979 36.6292300166285))',4326) and ()
                                                                          ^
            ) executing query: select "thematic_tiv",encode(ST_AsBinary(ST_Force2D("geom"),'NDR'),'hex') as geom,"aggregates_id" from (SELECT b.geom AS geom, a.peril_id, a.portfolio_id, a.tiv, a.thematic_tiv, a.aggregates_id FROM portfolios.aggregates a INNER JOIN gisdata.adm_1 b on a.gid = b.gid) AS c where geom && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((129.462890606979 36.6292300166285,129.462890606979 68.6423395678331,179.999999974944 68.6423395678331,179.999999974944 36.6292300166285,129.462890606979 36.6292300166285))',4326) and ()
            [Wed Jun  7 03:42:43 2017].523377 msPostGISLayerWhichShapes(): Query error. Error executing query. Check server logs
            [Wed Jun  7 03:42:43 2017].523434 msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'area_aggregates_tiv'.
            [Wed Jun  7 03:42:43 2017].523927 msFreeMap(): freeing map at 0x560aa573b6c0.
```

I'm sure something's changed in the way I'm supposed to configure the mapfile, but I can't figure out what it is.

EDIT: I've tried eliminating the joins by creating a table with all the necessary data. In this case, I have:

```
            DATA "geom from portfolios.area_aggregates_join using SRID=4326 using unique aggregates_id"
```

Yet I still get the same error. That "and ()" at the end of the final query that's causing the syntax error is bothering me.

Comment: Are you sure that is the query that is failing.  Your debug output doesn't seem to match.  For example in your debug output "thematic_tiv" is the only field that shows up.  Only thing I can think of that might be an issue is if you are passing in params.  I don't see that though but I think you'd need to put in validation for them - see http://mapserver.org/cgi/runsub.html

Comment: It appears to me that the debug output matches. I'll take a look at the link you provided. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out. The mapfile wasn't the only thing influencing the rendering of tiles, there were also modifications to the configuration through PHP and Mapscript.

Whereas in Mapscript 6.4 I could do the following:

```
            $layer->setFilter('column=value')
```

I had to do this in Mapscript 7.0.5:

```
            $layer->setProcessing('NATIVE_FILTER=column=value')
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the question and the hint in your answer. I am also searching for the error you posted but without MapScript. But I also got the feeling that it has something to do with the FILTER resp missing FILTER Parameter in my Postgis-Layer ... `syntax error at or near ")"`